# Regex for specific number

Tags: regex

I need regular expression for ID number,
it's 9 numbers and the first number must be 4 or 9 or 8.

can some one help ?

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working? (If this is homework please tag it as such.)

Comment: No it's not Homework, it's for my graduation project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[489][0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: Regarding your comment on @Jellicle's answer, the anchors are not mandatory in some engines depending on how you inkove it.  In Java, for example, if you were using the standard `String.matches()` or `Matcher.matches()` you don't need them, but if you were doing `Matcher.find()` you would.  That answer was deleted so I'm leaving it here as it's also relevant to this answer.